# nodejs download files from sftp

Tags: node.js, sftp

I need to download some `.txt.pgp` files from `sftp`. I've tried **npm** `ssh2`, `ssh2-sftp-client` and `node-ssh` without any success.

The closest I got so far is the list of the files in the remote folder using `sftp.readdir` (`ssh2`) or `sftp.list` (`ssh2-sftp-client`).

I've tried `pipe` and `fs.createWriteStream` and `sftp.fastGet` but there's no file saved on my local machine.

```
const conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client :: ready');

    conn.sftp((err, sftp) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        sftp.readdir('out', (err, list) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            list.forEach(item => {
                console.log(item.filename);

                const fileName = item.filename;

                sftp.fastGet(fileName, fileName, {}, downloadError => {
                    if(downloadError) throw downloadError;

                    console.log("Succesfully uploaded");
                });
            })
            conn.end();
        });
    });
}).connect(config);
```

**OR**

```
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const sftp = new Client();

sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
    return sftp.list('out');
})
.then(files => {
    // console.log(files);
    if (files.length > 0) {
        console.log('got list of files!');
    }

    files.map(file => {
        const fileName = file.name;

        sftp.get(fileName)
        .then(() => {
            fs.writeFile(fileName);
        }); 
    })
})
.then(() => {
    sftp.end();
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding your first attempt (with the `ssh2` module), there are three issues that I can see:

1. You are calling `conn.end()` outside of a series of preceding async functions, which is almost definitely causing the SSH session to close before you've finished downloading the files.
2. You are not providing the `sftp.fastGet()` function with the correct path to the remote file. Earlier in the code, you call `sftp.readdir()` with the remote directory argument `'out'`, which returns a list of files relative to the remote directory. (Point is: you need to prepend the remote directory to the file name to create a correctly qualified path.)
3. You're not handling the stream event `error`, so I suspect you're not getting useful error messages to help troubleshoot.

Try something like:

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const conn = new Client();    
const sshOpt = someFunctionThatPopulatesSshOptions();    
const remoteDir = 'out';

conn.on('ready', () => {
  conn.sftp((err, sftp) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    sftp.readdir(remoteDir, (err, list) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      let count = list.length;
      list.forEach(item => {
        let remoteFile = remoteDir + '/' + item.filename;
        let localFile = '/tmp/' + item.filename;
        console.log('Downloading ' + remoteFile);
        sftp.fastGet(remoteFile, localFile, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Downloaded to ' + localFile);
          count--;
          if (count <= 0) {
            conn.end();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
conn.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('SSH connection stream problem');
  throw err;
});
conn.connect(sshOpt);
```

This should address all the issues I mentioned. Specifically:

1. We are using a `count` variable to ensure the SSH session is closed only after all files are downloaded. (I know it is not pretty.)
2. We are prepending `remoteDir` to all of our remote file downloads.
3. We're listening for the `error` event in our `conn` stream.